# My variables are integers but I get console error with unsupported operands when I try to add them together

Tags: python

When I try to run this code

```py
budget = 500
x = 1
y = 1
bet = 0
totalsum = 0
x = input("enter result:")
bet = input("enter bet:")
y = input("you bet on?:")
if x == y:
    bet = (bet) * 2
    totalsum = budget + bet
    budget = totalsum
    print("your winnings:", totalsum)
    print("your budget:", budget)
if x != y:
    totalsum = budget - bet
    budget = totalsum
    print("your winnings:", totalsum)
    print("your budget:", budget)
if budget < 0:
    print("you lost :(")
```

I get a console error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "main.py", line 19, in 
>   totalsum = budget + bet                                                                                                                                                         TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
>   Program finished with exit code 1

I don't understand why. Both those values are set to have a numerical value so why is one of them a string? (I think that it what it means by 'str')

Comment: ```input()``` returns ```str``` on default - you need to replace every ```input(...)``` with ```int(input(...))```

Comment: Thanks your answer was the best because I understood as well why bet wasnt an integer while others just fed me with the answer (but thanks to those too of course)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any value you get from **`input`** will always be a string, hence your error.  To fix this, cast it to an int:

```
bet = int(input("enter bet:"))
```

Answer (score 3):

Your bet is *not* an integer, it is a string. Cast it to an integer with `int(bet)`.

Comment: I don't think that *casting* is a thing in python. The word you are looking for is convert, which is what `int(bet)` is doing.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add a string to an int

Do this instead:

```
totalsum = budget + int(bet)
```